# .Net Entity Framework - Enable-Migrations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Can anyone help me? I have an ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2022 running on .Net 4.6.1. I have a problem with Entity Framework.

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
>
> File name: 'EntityFramework, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyName, ObjectHandleOnStack requestingAssembly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName, RuntimeAssembly requestingAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
> at System.Data.Entity.Tools.ReflectionExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String dataDirectory, String configurationFile, String rootNamespace, String language) in /*/src/ef6/ReflectionExecutor.cs:line 35
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor() in /*/src/ef6/Commands/ProjectCommandBase.cs:line 85
> at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.MigrationsEnableCommand.Execute() in /*/src/ef6/Commands/MigrationsEnableCommand.cs:line 40
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.CommandBase. <>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0() in /*/src/ef6/Commands/CommandBase.cs:line 28
> at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args) in /*/src/ef6/CommandLineUtils/CommandLineApplication.cs:line 115
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args) in /*/src/ef6/Program.cs:line 40
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

??

Thank you for help

Comment: There are many previous examples of this message being asked about in SE sites. What research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Try using  EntityFramework6\Enable-Migrations the cmdlet has been changed by Microsoft.

Comment: still that same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: PM>  EntityFramework6\Enable-Migrations

The target context 'ProductionManagment.Models.CalculatorContext' is not constructible. Add a default constructor or provide an implementation of IDbContextFactory.